# AWS Increase CPU Credit Balance without Turning off the Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a process running on an AWS EC2 micro instance. It's been throttled because I've ran out of CPU Credit balance. I can't stop the process that is running, but I want to stop it throttling. Is there any way to increase my CPU Credit Balance without turning off the instance? I'm happy to pay Amazon some money to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

You can use [T2 Unlimited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-unlimited.html):

> T2 Unlimited instances can burst above the baseline for as long as required. This enables you to enjoy the low T2 instance hourly price for a wide variety of general-purpose applications, and ensures that your instances are never held to the baseline performance. ​The basic T2 hourly instance price automatically covers all CPU usage spikes if the average CPU utilization of a T2 Unlimited instance over a rolling 24-hour period is at or below the baseline. For a vast majority of general-purpose workloads, T2 Unlimited instances provide ample performance without any additional charges. **If the average CPU utilization exceeds the baseline over a 24-hour period, there is a flat additional rate per vCPU-hour.**
>
> ...
>
> You can switch from Standard to Unlimited, and from Unlimited to Standard, at any time on a running or stopped instance. For more information, see [Launching a T2 Instance as Unlimited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-how-to.html#launch-t2) and [Modifying the Credit Option for CPU Usage of a T2 Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-how-to.html#modify-t2).

Answer (score 3):

> *Why can't I just pay Amazon some money to do this?*

Who says you can't?

Activate the T2 Unlimited feature on the instance, and that's exactly what will happen.

> T2 Unlimited is a configuration option for T2 instances that can be set at launch, or enabled at any time for a running or stopped T2 instance.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-unlimited.html

This feature removes the performance cap. First it borrows against the credits you would earn over the next 24 hours, and then charges you for replenishing them, if needed, up to $0.05 per vCPU per hour, based on how hard you're really driving the instance.